# What are the uses of these four to-infinitives?

Tags: infinitives

> I shook my head: I could not see how poor people had the means of being kind; and then **to** learn to speak like them, **to** adopt their manners, **to** be uneducated, **to** grow up like one of the poor women I saw sometimes nursing their children or washing their clothes at the cottage doors of the village of Gateshead: no, I was not heroic enough to purchase liberty at the price of caste. (Jane Eyre)

What are the uses of these four to-infinitives? The syntax is not clear to me. How is this sentence put together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The infinitive clause, often with subject implied rather than stated, is a common literary figure for placing a hypothetical action before the reader (or, in narrative or drama, before another character or oneself) as a question, or for contemplation.

> **To** be or not **to** be: that is the question.

The character or reader is depicted as turning the possible action over in his mind: “Suppose I were **to** do such-and-such?”.

The figure may be multiplied for rhetorical effect; two classic instances in English literature are Hamlet's and Claudio's soliloquies:

> **To** die: **to** sleep;
> No more; and, by a sleep **to** say we end
> The heart-ache and the thousand natural shocks
> That flesh is heir to, ’tis a consummation
> Devoutly to be wish’d. **To** die, **to** sleep;
> **To** sleep: perchance **to** dream: ay, there’s the rub ...
>
> Ay, but **to** die, and go we know not where;
> **To** lie in cold obstruction and **to** rot;
> This sensible warm motion **to** become
> A kneaded clod; and the delighted spirit
> **To** bathe in fiery floods, or **to** reside
> In thrilling region of thick-ribbed ice;
> **To** be imprison’d in the viewless winds,
> And blown with restless violence round about
> The pendant world; or **to** be worse than worst
> Of those that lawless and incertain thoughts
> Imagine howling: ’tis too horrible!

So in Brontë's passage Jane is examining, one after another (*seriatim* is a nice word for impressing your professors), various aspects of what it would really mean for her **to** embrace poverty, and concluding that the price of liberty is too high.

Comment: Arguably you could say there's implicit elision of *"I could not see how"* before each *"to"*. But given the final clause, I think the "missing" text would be more appropriately expressed as *"I feel a certain obligation [to do this, that, and the other]"*. Such substitutions don't really work for the Shakespeare stuff anyway, but in the end you're quite right that the underlying process is one of presenting hypothetical scenarios.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Yes, that's the difference between the novel and the drama; in the drama, the actor has to pick a reading, in the novel the reader picks his own.

Comment: Nice juxtaposition! I'm (belatedly) watching a lot more movies now than I used to back in the days when I was an insatiable reader, and I do indeed find that although it can often be more "engrossing" (or at least, *easier to become engrossed*), drama does tend to cast the audience in a more "passive" role. Basically, the director, actors, and others do much more of the work for you, but inevitably you end up with *their* take more than your own "creative interpretation". I do enjoy them, but really, movies are for lazy readers!

Answer (score 2):

In this passage, Charlotte Brontë emphasized the gap between gentlefolk and the poor by giving four reasons, one after another, rather than just one example.

Use of *to* for the latter three verbs is optional: that is, if she had preferred to do so, she could have written “to learn ..., adopt ..., be uneducated, grow up...” instead of “to learn ..., to adopt ..., to be uneducated, to grow up...”.  However, the rhetorical [parallelism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_%28rhetoric%29) of the passage is improved by repeating the *to* before each verb.